# Solana Rent Sysvar empty

Tags: rent

I'm creating a local cluster with solana version 1.9.29, then I upgrade to solana 1.13.6 by restarting whole validators. I'm facing issue that Rent Sysvar account is empty so any programs using rent sysvar are all error.

```
curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0","id": 1,"method": "getAccountInfo","params": ["SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111", {"encoding":"jsonParsed"}]}'
Result:
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"context":{"apiVersion":"1.13.6","slot":10577180},"value":null},"id":1}
```

As I investigate, Solana required new accounts must be rent exempt, so is this reason for Rent Sysvar account is deleted by Garbage Collector? And do you know how to reinitialize Rent Sysvar?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your ledger got corrupted at some point, because this works as expected on a fresh 1.13.6 test validator. In one window:

```
$ solana-test-validator -r
```

And in the other:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0","id": 1,"method": "getAccountInfo","params": ["SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111", {"encoding":"jsonParsed"}]}'
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"context":{"apiVersion":"1.13.6","slot":44},"value":{"data":{"parsed":{"info":{"burnPercent":50,"exemptionThreshold":2.0,"lamportsPerByteYear":"3480"},"type":"rent"},"program":"sysvar","space":17},"executable":false,"lamports":1009200,"owner":"Sysvar1111111111111111111111111111111111111","rentEpoch":0}},"id":1}
```

If you don't need your existing ledger, can you try resetting it with the `-r` flag?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason because I upgraded Solana 1.9.29 to 1.10.41 without enabling feature `rent_for_sysvars` in `sdk/src/feature_set.rs`.